# Unable to boot ubuntu 16.04 from USB stick on Windows 10 machine

Tags: boot, usb

I am testing the feasibility of using Ubuntu in place of Windows/Mac for my company.
Using a new laptop pre-loaded with Windows 10 Home Version 1703...

Here's what I've done so far:

Downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.3 to my hard drive.

Followed the instructions under "Create a bootable USB stick on Windows" which uses a downloaded version of Rufus - and specifying the ISO file type as per the tutorial. This step seemed to go fine.

I have verified that the usb stick in the F: drive contains Ubuntu.

First, I just rebooted the laptop but it did not recognize a bootable module in the F: drive.

Then I rebooted again holding down the F12 key. Same behavior.

Then I rebooted again while repeatedly pressing and releasing the F12 key. This time the re-boot was interrupted. I got a screen that said:

Choose an option: Continue, Use a device, Troubleshoot, Turn off PC

I chose Use a device. This brought up a new screen with the following choices:
ATA HDD; ATAPI; PCI LAN; USB FDD; USB HDD; USB CD.

I clicked on USB FDD.

The machine completed the boot, but ignored the F drive and came up in Windows.

I believe I have reviewed all of the FAQs and tutorials that might pertain to this question.

To get this far, I have used up several hours of my time and essentially most of my weekend.

If anybody has any ideas I would appreciate it. Otherwise I think I'll just have to report back that Ubuntu is not a good match for our company.

Comment: it is USB:HDD, storage devices are labeled HDD: FDD is a floppy disk. PS -- the fact that you can notlaunch an external drive has nothing to do with ubuntu, or any other OS.

Comment: Tried USB:HDD. No change in behavior. Not sure what the second part of your comment is supposed to mean.

Comment: What brand/model system? Some need you to turn on allow USB boot. And/Or turn off UEFI Secure Boot. Are drives set to AHCI? Generally USB installer not seen as USB device but as another hard drive with many BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: "Otherwise I think I'll just have to report back that Ubuntu is not a good match for our company."...  this problem you are having is unrelated to ubuntu, but rather the method you made the USB or the computer itself.  As oldfred stated, secure boot has to  be turned off.

Comment: I was able to find the screen to change "boot mode" from UEFI, but the only other choice was "Legacy Support".

That did not change the behavior.

My only guess is that this machine will not allow booting from a USB stick.

Any recommendations as to preferred hardware for Ubuntu? It has to be relatively inexpensive because this is just an initial feasibility test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)